# Searching user profiles on Twitter

Tags: search, twitter

I found a number of similar questions on SO but they are all are either 2+ years old or aren't exactly what I am looking for.

All I would like to do is obtain a list of twitter users whose bio/profile contains certain terms (scientist, democrat, 'dog lover', etc.).

I've considered using a google site search but so far the results are incredibly noisy.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!
CS

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API supports a People Search similar to the website's "[Find on Twitter](https://twitter.com/invitations/find_on_twitter)" search feature. Although you can not directly search using only profile descriptions, it appears that the description content is used as part of the search space. If you can think of a way to narrow down your results even further by directly searching the returned users' descriptions, you should be able to do what you're looking for. Check out the [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/search) for more info.

Example:

Try searching for "husband father of three", and you get [these results](https://twitter.com/search/users?q=husband%20father%20of%20three&category=people&source=find_on_twitter), which obviously are returned because of the profile descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I have used one tool to search twitter profiles using keywords and many advance filters. I love the information which has been provided by the FollowerSearch tool. The information was very specific, which helps me to analyze the public [**twitter profiles**](https://www.followersearch.com/search-twitter-bios).
One of the best tools for quickly searching among the 800 million public Twitter accounts in the database is FollowerSearch.
With FollowerSearch, you can quickly conduct searches for Twitter influencers and Twitter bios across its massive database of more than 800 million Twitter profiles. You may look for Twitter profiles based on information like their location, line of work, number of followers, etc.

**Twitter Influencer Profile Search**

A Twitter bios search will assist you in simplifying the process, whether you're looking for influencers or new talent. You can discover Twitter folks who share your interests. Find out exact information on all the accounts whose bios contain your search term.

- Identify key accounts and Twitter influencers that have required terms in their Twitter bios.
- Look up new and budding talent.
- Find Twitter users with similar interests.
- Search Twitter profile or Search Twitter bios for any desired term.

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool that does exactly what your looking for.  Find70 let's you search for twitter profiles by their twitter bio.  In fact, you can set up as many search filters as you want and define your own weighting for each filter.  In your example above, you could search for: scientist, democrat, 'dog lover' and it would return all the accounts that have those in the bio.  This can be combined with other filters too.  Here it is http://www.find70.com/?t=stack